# SLF4J and JUL(java.util.logging) is not working on IBM Domino

Tags: xpages, slf4j, lotus-domino, java.util.logging

I am trying to get SLF4J and JUL working on domino for logging. I have created a custom handler called 'DominoGraphHandler' to write logs to the database. When the code is invoked through Xpages, it throws an exception. SLF4J and log4J combination also did not work. Is there a way to get the SLF4J working on domino. Following is the sample code and the exception details.

```
public void testJUL()
{
    java.util.logging.Logger jLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.app.log");
    jLogger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
    jLogger.addHandler(new DominoGraphHandler());
    jLogger.warning("warning message");
}
```

**Xpages Error Message:**

Error 500

HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

**domino/workspace/logs/error-log-0.xml**

```
<CommonBaseEvent creationTime="2017-11-15T17:41:18.338+05:30" globalInstanceId="ELc0a80aa500015fbf94954000000006" msg="CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /logging.nsf/log.xsp - HTTP Code: 500" severity="50" version="1.0.1">
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:level" type="noValue">
        <children name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:name" type="string"> 
            <values>SEVERE</values>
        </children>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName" type="string">
        <values>com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName" type="string">
        <values>service</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
        <values>java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener (initialization failure)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:461)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.initModule(NSFComponentModule.java:498)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.createNSFModule(NSFService.java:752)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.loadModule(NSFService.java:735)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:588)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)&#xA;Caused by: </values>
        <values>com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener (initialization failure)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:89)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.BootStrap.init(BootStrap.java:82)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.ConfigureCoreListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureCoreListener.java:39)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:453)&#xA;&#x9;... 8 more&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener (initialization failure)&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.Delegation.newInstance(Delegation.java:80)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.Delegation.getImplementation(Delegation.java:68)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.getListener(CLBootStrap.java:150)&#xA;&#x9;at co</values>
        <values>m.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:81)&#xA;&#x9;... 11 more&#xA;</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="" location="pilotdev5" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="" threadId="0" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
        <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
    </situation>
</CommonBaseEvent>
```

Comment: What says trace-log-0.xml?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError -> how did you install the JARs?